# How to properly sanitize/escape the message text in a PHP contact us form?

Tags: php, escaping, sanitization, contact-form

What do I need to do to the message text once it's submitted so that it doesn't interfere with the email headers, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the message you don't need no special sanitization.

But for the Subject and whatever else headers (i.e. To, From, CC etc) check for the **newline** characters

Answer (score 0):

[Fortunately, PHP has a bunch of useful sanitizing filters for your needs.](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php)

Then you can use [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php):

```
filter_var($yourData, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
```

If you are working with a database, you should use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for some protection against injections.

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
mysql_real_escape_string()
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: ummm.... [no](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) ... this is both deprecated and just wrong.

Comment: just wrong? it does carry out sanitisation and escape functionality, which is what the question asked.

Comment: database != email... For example newlines are valid in a database field but are not for the Subject header on an email. plus for proper return on mysql_real_escape_string you need to have an active connection to a database ... completely irrelevant to this situation.